# What's a consistent way to get the safe area insets for the iPhone X in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, iphone-x

I am currently updating some views for the iPhone X. According to [this blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/making-ios-11-even-easier-xamarin-forms/) it should be fairly streight-forward, but - like always - it's not as smooth as it's supposed to be.

If you are using the recommended way

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
}
```

the items of the View are given a `Margin` according to the safe area insets, but this applies to views like `SearchBar`, too, which already adapt to the insets out of the box. Using the code above will result in the gray background of the search bar not taking the whole width, which looks quite strange.

Fortunately the `On<iOS>` has an extension method `SafeAreaInsets()` which returns the correct insets - under certain conditions - which one for example can assign to a `BindableProperty`. Unfortunately the conditions under which we can obtain the insets are not very consistent.

- When `OnSizeAllocated` is called the first time, `SafeAreaInsets()` will return `0,0,0,0`
- When the view is shown `SafeAreaInsets()` returns the correct value (in `OnAppearing`)
- `OnSizeAllocated` is called multiply after rotation

  - The first time `SafeAreaInsets()` returns the correct value
  - The second time `SafeAreaInsets()` returns `0,0,0,0`

My current working solution is, to override both and only set my bindable property (which is bound to my views) if the `Thickness` returned by `SafeAreaInsets()` is not `default(Thickness)`.

**I'd like to know** if there is a standard way to always get the correct insets, without having to check if the insets have a sound value.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: It would be worth mentioning which version of Xamarin.Forms you are using, in case it is/was a bug.

Answer (score 6):

I did a bit of research on this. Here's couple of my thoughts:

1. You could actually set the `UseSafeArea` in XAML ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/ios#enabling-the-safe-area-layout-guide)) - that's just FYI
2. The setting of the `SafeArea` happens when using [this extension method](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/271cb309a6d84e1399ae5f7c153deac54ad0472b/Xamarin.Forms.Core/PlatformConfiguration/iOSSpecific/Page.cs#L148), which basically sets the `SafeAreaInsetsPropertyKey` property and then the page `Padding` is updated in the `UpdatePadding` method. The question here is, what calls that extension method and sets it then? I checked the Xamarin.Forms github repo and the answer is simple. It gets called from the `PageRenderer`, when the [`ViewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/768649bcd4b857a67d13ca6d73eb3361aed82b2e/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PageRenderer.cs#L66) is called by the [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2891116-viewsafeareainsetsdidchange). Which means that you don't know exactly when iOS decides to inform you about the current `SafeArea` - the issues that you're seeing with different values of the inset at different times.

I know it's definitely not what anyone wants but you could override the default iOS `PageRenderer` and hook up to the `ViewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` override. Once it's called you could be 100% sure that you have current `SafeArea` inset value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it's not 100% what I need. I am rather looking at edge cases I have to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I used a subscription to change the property value `SafeAreaInsets`. This complemented the incorrect solution with `OnSizeAllocated`.

```
public bool WasAppeared { get; private set; }

public CustomContentPage() : base()
{
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        PropertyChanged += CustomContentPage_PropertyChanged;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    WasAppeared = true;

    SetSafeArea();
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    WasAppeared = false;

    base.OnDisappearing();
}

private void CustomContentPage_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!WasAppeared)
        return;

    if (e.PropertyName == "SafeAreaInsets")
        SetSafeArea();
}

protected void SetSafeArea()
{
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.iOS)
        return;
}
```